# Customize QGIS Leaflet webpage

Tags: javascript, leaflet, qgis-plugins, html, qgis-processing

I created a webpage QGIS map using the Leaflet plugins, how to customize , put mouse over, then features will zoom automatically while you mouse on click on the map features, and also automatically zoom the features while you click its layer found in map legend.

Comment: For questions involving code, after narrowing the focus of this question to just one aspect of it, we will need you to include a working code snippet that shows what you have tried and where you are stuck.